# How to use iTerm2 in a server

Tags: terminal, iterm2

I just changed my regular terminal to iTerm2 terminal. I'm using iTerm2 with zsh shell in my local and can use all the features of iTerm2. However, when I ssh to virtual machines (on servers), the terminal changes to the virtual machine's native terminal running shell sh. So, the interface also changes, and I can't use iTerm2 features anymore on that server. I was wondering if there's anything I can do to still be able to use iTerm2 features in those servers? Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. General MacOS usage questions should be posted to [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: What features are you referring to? Are they iTerm2 features or zsh features?

Comment: No, you cannot really because you are into the remote host and it's environment. There are maybe some tricks but those are probably not easy to implement.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, zsh features. For example, I can't do reverse-i-search, etc.